# Trying to read a list of floats, integers, and strings from a file with sscanf() in C is not working as expected

Tags: c, csv, io, formatting

I am working on a program that reads a very large table from a file, periodic table to be precise.

```
struct periodic *createTable(){

char format[] ="%d\t%3s\t \
                     %20s\t%f\t \
                     %100[^\t]\t%f\t \
                     %d\t%f\t%d\t \
                     %d\t%d\t%20[^\t]\t \
                     %7s\t%17[^\t]\t \
                     %d\t%d\t%f\t \
                     %40[^\t]\t%7s\n";


struct periodic *tablePtr = malloc(sizeof(*tablePtr)*num_elements);
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("periodictable.csv","r");
char buff[150];

int i,err;
for(i=0;i<num_elements;i++){
    if(fgets(buff,150,fp)){
        printf("%s\n",buff);
        err = sscanf(buff,format,&(tablePtr->num),&(tablePtr->sym),&(tablePtr->name),
               &(tablePtr->weight),&(tablePtr->config),&(tablePtr->neg),
               &(tablePtr->neg),&(tablePtr->rad),&(tablePtr->ion_rad),
               &(tablePtr->vdW_rad),&(tablePtr->IE_1),&(tablePtr->EA),
               &(tablePtr->oxi_st),&(tablePtr->stn_st),&(tablePtr->bond_type),
               &(tablePtr->melt),&(tablePtr->boil),&(tablePtr->dens),
               &(tablePtr->type),&(tablePtr->year));
        printf("\n\nMatches:%d\n",err);
        printf("%d\n",tablePtr->num);
        printf("%s\n",tablePtr->sym);
        printf("%s\n",tablePtr->name);
        printf("%f\n",tablePtr->weight);
        printf("%s\n",tablePtr->config);
        printf("%f\n",tablePtr->neg);
        printf("%d\n",tablePtr->rad);
        printf("%f\n",tablePtr->ion_rad);
        printf("%d\n",tablePtr->vdW_rad);
        printf("%d\n",tablePtr->IE_1);
        printf("%d\n",tablePtr->EA);
        printf("%s\n",tablePtr->oxi_st);
        printf("%s\n",tablePtr->stn_st);
        printf("%s\n",tablePtr->bond_type);
        printf("%d\n",tablePtr->melt);
        printf("%d\n",tablePtr->boil);
        printf("%f\n",tablePtr->dens);
        printf("%s\n",tablePtr->type);
        printf("%d\n",tablePtr->year);

    }
}

}
```

format[] is a string containing all my formatting codes
The file is read and each line is put into a string called buff.
Buff is read and the values for each line parsed.

From the very first line, I encounter some problems.

The first five values are returned properly in those print statements below.

1
H
Hydrogen
1.00794
1s1

But then the next three values are just zero, and from there everything just kind of falls apart from there. I have no idea what is going wrong and how to fix it. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: It's been more than a quarter of a century since it was necessary to write multiline strings like that with backslashed newlines (and far too many spaces on the next line).  You can use string concatenation: `"this string" " and this string"` will be treated as `"this string and this string"` even if the two strings are on separate lines with no backslash at the end of the line.  (OK; I exaggerate slightly.  The standard that meant it was unnecessary is over a quarter of a century old — C89/C90.  But it was probably 5 years before the facility was relatively widely available.  Nevertheless, …)

Comment: You read two values into `&tablePtr->neg` because you pass that twice.  Please show 1-4 lines of the data.  Note that the `\t` in the format is the same as blanks — any white space character in the format string matches zero or more white space characters.  Also, 150 characters for the line is rather short given that the `config` can be up to 100 characters (so the member must be at least `char config[101];`).  It would be helpful to have the structure definition; it is a nuisance having to reverse engineer it.  You should compile with more compilation warnings enabled — or a better compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Diagnosis

As noted in the comments, it's been more than a quarter of a century since it was necessary to write multiline strings like that with backslashed newlines (and far too many spaces on the next line). You can use string concatenation:

```
"this string" " and this string"
```

will be treated the same as:

```
"this string and this string"
```

even if the two strings are on separate lines with no backslash at the end of the line. (I exaggerate slightly. The standard that meant it was unnecessary is over a quarter of a century old — C89/C90. But it was probably 5 years before the facility was relatively widely available. Nevertheless, any code written in the current millennium can use string concatenation instead of using backslashes at the ends of lines.)

You read two values into `&tablePtr->neg` because you pass that twice (but you tried to read it as a `float` and as an `int` — it's 'make your mind up' time). Note that the `\t` in the format is the same as blanks — any white space character (not in a scanset) in the format string matches zero or more white space characters. Also, 150 characters for the line is rather short given that the config can be up to 100 characters (so the member must be at least `char config[101];`). It would be helpful to have the structure definition; it is a nuisance having to reverse engineer it.

I also suggested using more compiler warning flags, or a better compiler.  However, that was not entirely helpful.  Because the format string is in a variable, not a constant, the extra warnings aren't available.  I got around it by creating a macro to make a constant string for the format, and then all hell broke loose because you were passing `&tablePtr->sym` (which is a `char (*)[4]` and not a `char *`) — drop the `&`.

You read the year as a 7-character string but try to print it as an integer which is not a good idea.

#### Revised code

This leads to this manufactured code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct periodic
{
    int num;
    char sym[4];
    char name[21];
    float weight;
    char config[101];
    float neg;
    int rad;
    float ion_rad;
    int vdW_rad;
    int IE_1;
    int EA;
    char oxi_st[21];
    char stn_st[8];
    char bond_type[18];
    int melt;
    int boil;
    float dens;
    char type[41];
    char year[8];
};

#define FORMAT "%d\t%3s\t"                 \
               "%20s\t%f\t"                \
               "%100[^\t]\t%f\t"           \
               "%d\t%f\t%d\t"              \
               "%d\t%d\t%20[^\t]\t"        \
               "%7s\t%17[^\t]\t"           \
               "%d\t%d\t%f\t"              \
               "%40[^\t]\t%7s\n"          

int num_elements = 120;

struct periodic *createTable(void);

struct periodic *createTable(void)
{
//    char format[] = "%d\t%3s\t"                 // num, sym
//                    "%20s\t%f\t"                // name, weight
//                    "%100[^\t]\t%f\t"           // config, neg
//                    "%d\t%f\t%d\t"              // rad, ion_rad, vdW_rad
//                    "%d\t%d\t%20[^\t]\t"        // IE_q, EA, oxi_st
//                    "%7s\t%17[^\t]\t"           // stn_st, bond_type
//                    "%d\t%d\t%f\t"              // melt, boil, dens
//                    "%40[^\t]\t%7s\n";          // type, year

    struct periodic *tablePtr = malloc(sizeof(*tablePtr) * num_elements);
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("periodictable.csv", "r");
    char buff[150];

    int i, err;
    for (i = 0; i < num_elements; i++)
    {
        if (fgets(buff, 150, fp))
        {
            printf("Data: %s\n", buff);
            err = sscanf(buff, FORMAT, &(tablePtr->num), (tablePtr->sym), (tablePtr->name),
                         &(tablePtr->weight), (tablePtr->config), &(tablePtr->neg),
                         /*&(tablePtr->neg),*/ &(tablePtr->rad), &(tablePtr->ion_rad),
                         &(tablePtr->vdW_rad), &(tablePtr->IE_1), &(tablePtr->EA),
                         (tablePtr->oxi_st), (tablePtr->stn_st), (tablePtr->bond_type),
                         &(tablePtr->melt), &(tablePtr->boil), &(tablePtr->dens),
                         (tablePtr->type), (tablePtr->year));
            if (err != 19)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Conversion failure: %d OK\n", err);
                break;
            }
            printf("\n\nMatches:%d\n", err);
            printf("Num:    %d\n", tablePtr->num);
            printf("Sym:    %s\n", tablePtr->sym);
            printf("Name:   %s\n", tablePtr->name);
            printf("Weight: %f\n", tablePtr->weight);
            printf("Config: %s\n", tablePtr->config);
            printf("Neg:    %f\n", tablePtr->neg);
            printf("Rad:    %d\n", tablePtr->rad);
            printf("IonRad: %f\n", tablePtr->ion_rad);
            printf("vdWRad: %d\n", tablePtr->vdW_rad);
            printf("IE_1:   %d\n", tablePtr->IE_1);
            printf("EA:     %d\n", tablePtr->EA);
            printf("Oxi_St: %s\n", tablePtr->oxi_st);
            printf("Stn_St: %s\n", tablePtr->stn_st);
            printf("BondTp: %s\n", tablePtr->bond_type);
            printf("Melt:   %d\n", tablePtr->melt);
            printf("Boil:   %d\n", tablePtr->boil);
            printf("Dense:  %f\n", tablePtr->dens);
            printf("Type:   %s\n", tablePtr->type);
            printf("Year:   %s\n", tablePtr->year);
        }
    }
    return tablePtr;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct periodic *tbl = createTable();
    free(tbl);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the parentheses around arguments to `sscanf()` are superfluous.  A line such as:

```
&(tablePtr->weight), (tablePtr->config),
```

could perfectly well be written without the parentheses:

```
&tablePtr->weight, tablePtr->config,
```

#### Example run

Given a one-line data file with mostly fictitious data for Hydrogen:

```
1       H       Hydrogen        1.00794 1s1     -1.0001999      2       3.0002999       4       5       6       Oxy     Stn     Bond    -234    -236    1.01E-5 Gas     1723
```

the program produced the output:

```
Data: 1 H       Hydrogen        1.00794 1s1     -1.0001999      2       3.0002999       4       5       6       Oxy     Stn     Bond    -234    -236    1.01E-5 Gas     1723



Matches:19
Num:    1
Sym:    H
Name:   Hydrogen
Weight: 1.007940
Config: 1s1
Neg:    -1.000200
Rad:    2
IonRad: 3.000300
vdWRad: 4
IE_1:   5
EA:     6
Oxi_St: Oxy
Stn_St: Stn
BondTp: Bond
Melt:   -234
Boil:   -236
Dense:  0.000010
Type:   Gas
Year:   1723
```

Having 19 columns in a single input is painful.  It is helpful to use the string literal (disguised as a macro) for the format string; at least GCC can error check the types.